# How to parse yaml in ruby without type mapping

Tags: ruby, mapping, yaml, zipcode

I would like to get data from a Mysql dump in yaml (PHPMyAdmin), but data are not surrounded by quotation mark.

I have zipcode that can start by 0 and after parsing I get decimal version of octal value, in place of simple string.

How can I do to force Yaml parser not to do  auto-mapping, or just get all data as they are string ?

Thanks

== UPDATE ==

```
2185:
 id: 3274  
 civility: Mr  
 address: CROIX DES COMBES  
 zipcode: 04270
```

Comment: Can you show examples of your code and samples of the YAML being parsed where the values are not being transferred correctly? In my experience, if I create my YAML correctly Ruby will load it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your zipcode values are strings, which they probably should be in the database, and they are converted correctly to YAML, then they will be reconverted back into strings by Ruby's YAML parser:

```
require 'yaml'
zip = '01234'
```

If we treat it as a string, it converts correctly.

```
zip.to_yaml # => "--- \"01234\"\n"
YAML.load(zip.to_yaml) # => "01234"
```

If we treat it as an integer, it has its leading `0` dropped, which I'd expect.

```
zip.to_i.to_yaml # => "--- 1234\n"
YAML.load(zip.to_i.to_yaml) # => 1234
```

In your sample:

```
zipcode: 04270
```

`zipcode` is a YAML integer. It should be enclosed inside quotes to preserve its "stringness".

[Wikipedia's YAML article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Casting_data_types) has a nice example showing how data types are supposed to be disambiguated.

---

You can tweak all the instances of `zipcode` in the YAML before parsing it doing something like:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml_data = '2185:
 id: 3274  
 civility: Mr  
 address: CROIX DES COMBES  
 zipcode: 04270
'

yaml_data.gsub(/zipcode: (\d+)/, 'zipcode: "\1"') 
# => "2185:\n id: 3274  \n civility: Mr  \n address: CROIX DES COMBES  \n zipcode: \"04270\"\n"

YAML.load(yaml_data.gsub(/zipcode: (\d+)/, 'zipcode: "\1"')) 
# => {2185=>{"id"=>3274, "civility"=>"Mr", "address"=>"CROIX DES COMBES", "zipcode"=>"04270"}}
```

Comment: I know, but PhpMyAdmin dump don't add quotation mark to data in the YAML file, And I can't add manually or with a regexp the quotation mark. I think that it must be possible to config parser to get all data as simple string and not do the type mapping

Comment: I just looked at the underlying `syck` docs and don't see anything that would tell it to ignore what the data-types are in the file. The parser is doing what it should, given the data being presented to it. Since the YAML data is a text file, you could load and preprocess it to convert the zipcode field into a string, then parse it.

Comment: I can't validate your answer because it isn't the solution I want but thanks for the research.

Comment: "I can't validate your answer because it isn't the solution I want..." Something to consider: Sometimes the solution we want isn't practical or even possible for a variety of reasons. Preprocessing the incoming data to make it palatable to the next step is very common; I've had to do it many times dealing with malformed HTML and XML, just to be able to parse it. Elegance is desirable, but sometimes we have to throw that out the window and get our hands dirty, just to get something done.

Comment: I know but I already do what you told me with my coda and regexp replacement so, it's no a good reponse for me, I just want to know if we can do what I ask "Config a ruby Yaml parser to get all data in a string", And maybe one day a new parser will do that.

Comment: "maybe one day a new parser will do that". I'm not sure that will happen. YAML is a [well documented standard](http://yaml.org/), and MyPHPAdmin isn't generating valid YAML output. I think someone who has written a YAML parser will say MyPHPAdmin needs to fix their output.